# If a function returns two or more values and I wish to use one of the two in another function, how do I do that?

Tags: solidity, javascript

I have a function xyz :

```
uint256 a;
uint256 b;
function xyz() internal view return(uint256,uint256){
return (a,b);
}
```

Now, I wish to use the first return value in another function (for eg):

```
uint256 c;
function abc() public {
c += xyz().0; // c += a is desired
}
```

What should be the correct syntax.

Answer (score 5):

In Solidity you can ignore one or all of the returned values by just not assigning them to the variables:

```
(uint a, ) = xyz();
```

The code above would only get the first returned value and ignore the second one.

```
(, uint b) = xyz();
```

This code would only get the second returned value.

```
uint256 c;
function abc() public {
 (uint a, ) = xyz();
 c += a;
}
```

This is how you would do it with your example.

Comment: Thanks, that seems like a very simple solution indeed.